# Find and break on repeated runs

Tags: r

I have a vector with repeating patterns within it.  I want to break any where the repeating pattern of n length changes.
Here's the data:

```
x <- c(rep(1:4, 5), rep(5:6, 3), rep(c(1, 4, 7), 5), rep(c(1, 5, 7), 1), rep(2:4, 3))

##  [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 6 5 6 1 4 7 1 4 7 1 4 7 1 4 7 1 4 7 1 5 7 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4
```

I want to be able to find those places the pattern changes so it breaks like this:

[image]

I think `rle` may be of use but don't see how.

Comment: Upvoting but not sure this partitioning rule is well-defined. Can `1 1 2` be a repeating pattern or are nums always unique within a run?

Comment: Is there a maximum length a pattern can have?

Comment: @Frank I don't see a `1, 1, 2` but may be missing it.

Comment: I don't see what distinguishes two groups, `1 5 7` followed by `2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4`, from a single group, repeating only once of `1 5 7 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4` unless there's no repetition permitted within a group.

Comment: @FRANK me either I was hoping people have faced a similar problem in gene sequencing or something.

Comment: would it help to say that the pattern is a set that repeats, so @Frank 's `1 5 7` is not in the `2 3 4` set

Comment: @Frank I get it it, no the pattern `1, 1, 2` can not occur.  Items are unique within the repeating set.

Comment: I'd assume `115151` is broken as {1} {1515} {1}..?

Comment: @TylerRinker so you're thinking of this as a key of sorts, right? That the sequence is of distinct elements?

Comment: @Frank yes that is correct

Comment: @simpson yes they are distinct.  Frank clarifies this nicely.

Comment: @jeremycg Do you have an R implimentation?

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/matching-a-sequence-in-a-vector-td4389523.html#a4393453

Comment: Is the pattern always increasing?

Comment: Is it a fair assumption that longer patterns take precedence over shorter ones? So 5656 is a pattern and should not be broken as {5}{6}{5}{6}?

Comment: @Frank no not always increasing

Comment: @RHA yes longer patterns take precedence

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a function to do it. By the way, this is a problem in genetics - finding tandem repeats. [Here's a link to an algorithm paper](http://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/~gusfield/lineartime.pdf) that is a much better treatment than this, but much more complicated to implement.

The output is a vector of groups to split x into.

First a helper function:

```
factorise <- function(x) {
  x <- length(x)
  if(x == 1){return(1)}
  todivide <- seq(from = 2, to = x)
  out <- todivide[x %% todivide == 0L]
  return(out)
}
```

Now the main function:

```
findreps <- function(x, counter = NULL){
  if(is.null(counter)){
    counter <- c()
    maxcounter <- 0
  } else {
    maxcounter <- max(counter)
  }
  holding <- lapply(1:length(x), function(y){x[1:y]})
  factors <- lapply(holding, factorise)
  repeats <- sapply(1:length(factors), function(index) {any(sapply(1:length(factors[[index]]), function(zz) {all((rep(holding[[index]][1:(length(holding[[index]])/factors[[index]][zz])], factors[[index]][zz]))==holding[[index]])}))})
  holding <- holding[max(which(repeats))][[1]]
  if(length(holding) == length(x)){
    return(c(counter, rep(maxcounter + 1, length(x))))
  } else {
    counter <- c(counter, rep(maxcounter + 1, length(holding)))
    return(findreps(x[(length(holding) + 1):length(x)], counter))
  }
}
```

How it works:
It's a recursive function that runs, cuts off the biggest repeats group it can find from the start of the vector, and then runs until they are all gone.

First we make a `counter` for the final output.

Next, we split `x` into each subset starting from 1 into a list, `holding`.

Then we find all factors of the size of a group, except 1.

Then is the worst part. We take each subset of the biggest subset, and check if it is equal to the biggest subset in its group after being repeated the sensible amount of times.

```
findreps(x)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[37] 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

If you want non-repeats to be grouped, we can use a little `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

z <- data.frame(x = x, y = findreps(x))

z %>% mutate(y = ifelse(duplicated(y) | rev(duplicated(rev(y))), y, NA),
             holding = c(0, y[2:n()])) %>%
      fill(holding) %>%
      mutate(y = ifelse(is.na(y), holding +1, y)) %>%
      select(-holding)
```

Which gives:

```
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
[53] 7
```

Comment: This indeed works, nice.  Can I hold off on the check to give others a chance to respond.

Comment: @TylerRinker this goes back to the loosely defined rules Frank talked about above, but test this with `x <- c(rep(1:4, 5), rep(5:6, 3), rep(1:4, 5), rep(5:6, 3))`. I would expect you are looking for all `1`s in the result, but that is not the result we get. @jeremycg this looks great for the test case, but there are a number of edge cases I think this misses

Comment: see the edit - It now works on that test case, and on runs of singles in primes lengths. I removed the table and prime checks, but made the factorising smarter.

Answer (score 3):

I am almost there, but I doesn't work for the full 100% and it is getting late (zzz). First the code:

```
x <-c(rep(1:4, 5), rep(5:6, 3), rep(c(1, 4, 7), 5), rep(c(1, 5, 7), 1), rep(2:4, 3))

#The first break must be position 1
Xbreaklist <- 1

#We need a counter, a duplicate dataset 
counter <- 0
xx <- x

while (length(xx) > 0) {
#first we extract a pattern by looking for the first repeated number
Xpattern <- xx[1:(min(which(stri_duplicated(xx) == TRUE))-1)]

#then we convert the vector and the pattern into a string
XpatternS <- paste0(Xpattern, collapse="")
xxS <- paste0(xx, collapse="")

#then we extract all patterns and count them, multiply by length and add 1 
Xbreak <- 1 + (length(unlist(stri_extract_all_coll(xxS, XpatternS))) * length(Xpattern))

#break here if we reached the end 
if (Xbreak >= length(xx)) break

# We add that to the list of breaks
counter <- counter + Xbreak
Xbreaklist <- c(Xbreaklist, counter)

# then we remove the part of the list we're done with
xx <- xx[(Xbreak):length(xx)]
}

Xbreaklist
[1]  1 21 28 44 51
```

What is wrong with it? Two things:
1 A pattern that is not repeated takes the first occurrence of the next pattern with it: "121212 56 787878" gets split as ("121212 5678 7878")
2 Repeating patterns ("1212 5656 12 134") mess things up because `stri_extract_all_coll` takes them all out and hence length is to long.

Comment: So close :-) hopefully someone can move forward.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer but thought it better than posting in a comment.  It may get others to find a way to do this.

My idea was to split the vector into equal parts of size N.  Then to check if the successive chunk was a duplicate of the previous chunk.   I did this in a likely overly long way - I'm sure there must be an easier way to do it.

It seems to work ok and could form the basis of another way of going about this.  The downside is that it can't pick up the repeats that only occur once e.g. "157".

```
xx <- split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/N))  #split vector into equal chunks of size N
xx <- xx[-(length(xx))]  #get rid of uneven splitting of last vector

df <- do.call('rbind', xx) #bind together in a dataframe

results<-NULL  #loop to test if row is same as previous row (must be better way to do this)
for(i in 2:nrow(df)-1) {results[[i]] <- df[i,]==df[i+1,] }

results1 <- unlist(lapply(results, sum)) #count TRUEs in each result
results1[results1<N]<-0 #make all not equal to size of chunk (N) equal to zero

indices <- which(diff(results1)==-N)+1  #this is the first non-repeating group of N
indicesall <- (indices*N)+1 #to find location of next non-repeating id
```